# Tenemos [es6] y [ecmascript-2015] y las dos se refieren a lo mismo

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Tenemos [es6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) (34 preguntas) y [ecmascript-2015](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015) (36 preguntas). Ambas se refiere a ECMAScript 2015.

¿Cuál debe ser la etiqueta principal? ¿las hacemos sinónimo una de la otra o re-etiquetamos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece lo mismo que sea una u otra, lo importante es ordenarlo (el objetivo de tu propuesta).

Creo que tienen que ser sinónimos porque

1. Sería útil poder escribir cualquiera de las 2 para preguntar, buscar, etc.
2. Tendría altas chances <sup><sub>(léase probabilidades en España :-))</sub></sup> de que la vuelvan a crear y caer de nuevo en lo mismo.

No tendría ninguna queja en cuál se elija. Prefiero que alguien sugiera el sinónimo que sea y que se genere lo antes posible.

Como dato, en SO está como principal `ecmascript-6`, con `es6`, `es2015`, `ecmascript-2015` como sinónimos. En SOpt también `ecmascript-6` es la principal... Quizás deberíamos "seguir el palo".

Comment: De acuerdo en "seguir el palo". Ya sólo habría que ver quién puede crear el sinónimo. Seguramente requeriremos a un mod diamantado.

Comment: @Rubén podría generarla en una pregunta y proponer el sinónimo... Luego, al ser una etiqueta nueva, para la votación sí necesitaríamos a un mod

Comment: Alguna vez lo intenté con otra etiqueta y no funcionó. Tal vez era cosa de esperar algún proceso de recuento de votos en la etiqueta.

Comment: @Rubén ya sugerí a ambos sinónimos (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/synonyms)

Comment: @Rubén ¿Por qué estás proponiendo `es2016` <- `ecmascript-7`? ¿No va en contra de esta propuesta? Me imaginaba, cuando dijiste que estás de acuerdo con "seguir el palo", que la etiqueta principal hubiese sido `ecmascript-7`. ¿No te parece?

Comment: Quise hacerlo al revés pero me equivoqué

Comment: Hola ^^ En el reporte no estaba muy claro. Necesitais borrar la publicacion? (+@Rubén)

Comment: @lois6b simplemente eliminar este sinónimo sugerido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/es2016/synonyms, porque la idea es proponerlo en el sentido opuesto. ([Tag:ecmascript-7] y [tag:ecmascript-6] son las que se proponen como principales).

Comment: Ahh vale, Listo pues (https://i.imgur.com/5ie9y2H.png)

Comment: @lois6b no sé qué haríamos sin vos :-) Gracias capo

Comment: Yo solo soy una *herramienta* más. Vosotros sois los que proponeis cambios ^^

Comment: @lois6b : Muchas gracias . P.D. No me llegó notificación del mensaje con +@

Comment: @Rubén gracias a ti. la proxima vez dejo el  `+`  para el chat xD un saludo